# How to refresh the oldfiles list without restarting Vim?

Tags: filesystem

`:browse oldfiles<cr>` is useful for quickly navigating to a file I've worked on recently.

Sometimes though, I want to suspend `vim` and do some `grep` or `ack` search and find a new file that I'm interested in (let's call it `sneaky.h`). If I open a fresh `vim` using `vim sneaky.h` and then close it immediately, `sneaky.h` will appear in the `oldfiles` list the next time I launch Vim.

However, my original `vim` instance, the one I started before searching for `sneaky.h`, does not have the file in the `oldfiles` list.

Is there a way to direct vim to refresh the `oldfiles` list and populate it again without restarting vim?

Also, is there a more efficient way to get a file like `sneaky.h` into the `oldfiles` pool without opening it and closing it immediately?

Comment: Does `:rviminfo` do the trick? [`:h :rviminfo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#%3arviminfo).

Comment: Also what you want is to learn how to find a file from within vim. There are a lot of options to do that like the built-in `:find`, `grep`, the file explorer netrw or fuzzy finding plugins like [ctrl-p](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) or [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)

Comment: @statox: I guess that's true. If it isn't a file in the same directory and isn't `ctags`-able, I tend to search in the shell and use a fresh vim instance.

Is there a way to get a file into `.viminfo` without opening and closing it? The format of a bare bones `.viminfo` entry `> filename.txt`, next line `\t*\t<timestamp>\t0` seems simple enough to write a script for, but a "supported" way would be a bit nicer.

Comment: maybe you can use `:rviminfo!` (with explanationm ark) to force a re-read of the `.viminfo`.<br/>
<br/>
see `:h oldfiles` for more info.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Im not sure if it is possible to easily add files to `viminfo` but it is because it is not actually meant to be used this way. See [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What you actually need is a way to search for a file (you can do this in a lot of different ways) and then manipulate your `arglist` Take a look at these vimcast [arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/), [vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/), [file explorer](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/the-file-explorer/)

Comment: I am not certain `viminfo` can be properly shared across vim instances. To allow merging of information, neovim uses [`shada`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#shada) files instead of `viminfo` files. I imagine you need to look into using [MRU plugin](https://vimawesome.com/?q=mru) or roll your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't use the *oldfiles* list, the [MRU plugin](https://github.com/yegappan/mru) implements the functionality you are looking for:

> This plugin automatically stores the file names as you open/edit them in Vim.

You can configure the path of the file that stores the entries and the maximum number of entries it can hold. It supports FZF to filter the list.

(This answer was already mentioned by Peter Rincker in the comments above)